# Как создавать уникальный идентификатор для загружаемых картинок?

Tags: javascript

Нужно сгенерировать id для загружаемой картинки. Подскажите как правильно сделать?

```js
id = ??????????
let imageoneRef = await storageRef.child(`${id}`).put(fileone);
```

Если сделать так, нормально будет new Date().valueOf();
?

Comment: Смотря для чего это `id` нужно будет.

Comment: Можно генератором случайных чисел попробовать.

Comment: Нужно сгенерировать id для загружаемой картинки. Подскажите как правильно сделать?

Comment: `Math.random().toString(36).substring(2)`

Answer (score 2):

С помощью `Date.now();` значение всегда разное т.к. возвращает `unix timestamp`

```js
var id = Date.now();
console.log(id);
```

Comment: А если несколько картинок?

Comment: Оно генерит один и тот же код

Comment: let generatorId = () => {
                         return Date.now();
                    };
                let ImgOneId = generatorId();
                let ImgTwoId = generatorId();

Comment: У меня генерит разные ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Если выполнение кода занимает меньше миллисекунды, то последовательные вызовы метода `Date.now()` могут возвращать одинаковое значение. @sinevik, попробуйте `const newId = () => +String(performance.now()).replace('.', '') + Date.now(); `

Comment: Также можно создать UUID

Answer (score 1):

Один из способов создания уникальных и не повторяющихся идентификаторов...

```js
var Q;
Q = {};
Q.timeInterval;

function genUniqueID(kol) {
 Q.timeInterval = setTimeout(function() {
  document.querySelector('#demo').innerHTML += new Date().valueOf() + '<br>';
  kol--;
  if (kol > 0) {
   genUniqueID(kol);
  }
 }, document.querySelector('#i2').value);
}
```

```html
<div><input id="i1" type="number" value="5" style="width: 60px;"><label> - Количество</label><br>
<input id="i2" type="number" value="10" style="width: 60px;"><label> - Интервал в миллисекундах</label></div><br>
<div>
<button onclick="genUniqueID(document.querySelector('#i1').value);">Start</button>
<button onclick="clearTimeout(Q.timeInterval);">Stop</button>
<button onclick="document.querySelector('#demo').innerHTML = ''">Clear</button>
</div><br>
<div id="demo"></div>
```